# Unable to boot into Ubuntu after Ubuntu-Fedora Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, fedora

I tried to dual boot Ubuntu and fedora, but now I am unable to boot into my Ubuntu installation. Here is the situation
I had Ubuntu installed already on `/dev/sda2` and I resized it to create another partition `/dev/sda3` . I installed fedora 15 on `/dev/sda3` . Now I can boot into fedora but there in to option to go into Ubuntu. Swap partition is on `/dev/sda1`.

```
Swap /dev/sda1
Ubuntu /dev/sda2
Fedora /dev/sda3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fedora 15 still uses grub legacy for boot, and it overwrites Ubuntu's Grub 2 boot loader and menu. And Grub legacy does not find Ubuntu install out-of-the-box.

To restore Ubuntu's boot, all you have to do is [re-install grub2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27155).

Do this:

- Boot using Ubuntu's Live CD
- Open Nautilus, and double-click Ubuntu's partition. Take note of its mount point directory (if you labeled the partitions, it will be something like `/media/label`
- Now open terminal and issue:

  `sudo grub-install --root-directory=/media/your-ubuntu-label /dev/sda`
- You may boot into Ubuntu now.
- If you want to add Fedora 15 to Ubuntu's (grub2) boot list, do this:

  `sudo update-grub`

Comment: This procedure does not work anymore on Ubuntu 13.04 with Fedora 19. Any ideas?

Comment: Take back my comment, this might have worked, but I had installed fedora on top of an existing partition, and fsck kept trying to mount that because of my fstab.