# How to fix Ubuntu 12.04 boot, using Windows XP?

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, dual-boot, windows-xp

I installed Ubuntu **12.04** from USB. Now there is no option to choose Linux or Windows, because the boot-loader is missing.

1. Can I repair this using **Windows XP**, without using **Ubuntu** or
   a virtual machine?
2. Is there is any **software for Windows XP** (to act as boot-loader)?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean when you say your boot loader is *missing*? Are you able to start Ubuntu from your hard drive? If you can then possibly the GRUB boot menu is just hidden. Try pressing the `shift` key immediately after the BIOS boot completes and Ubuntu starts booting. This is supposed to force the GRUB boot menu to appear.

Comment: look at my answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/142750/after-installing-ubuntu-from-usb-grub2-cant-be-installed/142751#142751

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still need for windows see NeoSmart BCD 
You can get it [here](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

Requirements is Dot net framewrok 2x

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix it using a windows tool. To fix the bootloader you need an ubuntu live cd.

Comment: I answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why the trouble to fix Ubuntu boot using Windows tools if you can use Windows to download and burn an Ubuntu Live CD/USB and *then* use it to easily fix your boot?

Step by step would be:

1. Using Internet Explorer (or any other browser), got to
   http://www.ubuntu.com/download and download an Ubuntu ISO image. Any image will do it, it doesn't matter if it is or not the same version you have installed
2. Using your favorite windows cd burner software (Nero? Windows
   Explorer? Or try [this free one](http://infrarecorder.org/)), burn that ISO image to a blank
   CD. Or download [pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3) and burn it to a USB key.
3. Boot using this CD/USB, open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /mnt/ubuntu
   sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/ubuntu
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-directory=/mnt/ubuntu
   ```

*(that's assuming your boot hard drive is `sda` and your ubuntu partition is `sda2`. Numbers and letters may be different in your system, so check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/27179/11015) for detailed information)*

Your boot (and grub menu) will be restored. You can stop here, but it's recommended that, after booting Ubuntu, to issue a final touch:

```
sudo update-grub
```